# Bigfiles in Golang

Tags: go, bigdata

I am dealing with an application that contains millions of very small files and it s becoming a pain. It's very hard to transfer.

So, I thought of bigfiles or another virtual file system that could create a large file, containing all my data indexed.

How would one go about this in golang ? Do you have any lib to recommend?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended solution depends on your unposted requirements, such as do you need to modify the files? Do you need the ability to remove them? Do you need distributed storage etc?

If you only need to add new files which you don't intend to change, you may use [`github.com/icza/kvcache`](https://github.com/icza/kvcache) (disclosure: I'm the author). `kvcache` stores all entries in 2 files only (1 for index and 1 for data), and keeps the index in memory too, so lookups are as fast as possible, and transferring the files is equivalent to copying 2 files only.

MongoDB has [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) which gives you a file system-like API and allows you to store metadata for files and search them. The [`mgo`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2) library also supports accessing and using the GridFS, see the [`mgo.GridFS`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#GridFS) and [`mgo.GridFile`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#GridFile) types.

You may also opt to store your files in the cloud, there are countless services and Go client libraries, all of them providing basic search functionality.

Also be sure to check this question+answers on ServerFault:

[Storing a million images in the filesystem](https://serverfault.com/questions/95444/storing-a-million-images-in-the-filesystem)

Comment: I'd also note that pretty much "standard" [BoltDB](https://github.com/boltdb/bolt) appears to handle 1TB data sets—according to the project's docs. There's also a battle-tested [LevelDB](https://github.com/syndtr/goleveldb), but I'm not sure about its size limits.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a simple ZIP archive (supposedly with zero compression) would work for you? It has a natural index into the contents (file streams), so when you [open it using `archive/zip`](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#NewReader), you get back
[a slice of "file info blocks"](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#Reader),
each of which "knows" how to locate and read its corresponding file stream.
(There's even a way to get the offset of the file's data, and read it
directly—bypassing a no-op "decompressor" and checksum verification,
so you could explore this possible speed tweak if your measurements would
show the speed of accessing that data "the normal way" will be suboptimal.)

You could then create a map indexed by file names for fast access.

Or maybe go further and create a hierarchy of such maps
to simulate a "natural" directory tree.
Or maybe have several ZIP archives in a filesystem tree.

---

And naturally, if everything you'd want to have is a r/o blob of file stream blobs + index, that would be a reasonably straightforward thing to implement yourself—both for reading and writing. If you're not too much into designing stuff, I'd look at the [format of the Git "pack files"](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/pack-format.txt).

Comment: I have doubts about the efficiency of adding _millions_ of files into a zip archive. Someone should put it under tests...

Comment: @icza, sure, that was my doubt, too. Bu the OP explicitly mentioned that the files are "very small", so I naturally assumed they are small as, say, less than one KiB, and that might fit into a 4GB "standard ZIP" module—or maybe not.